# Building long term application Architecture

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, architecture

I am interested in learning how web application are evolving. The idea is that if new technologies or design methodologies should be introduced in java based web application, what would be the top 5-10 technologies worth exploring? Also it would be helpful if someone can point out good books or online resources to conduct this research.

Comment: Not sure about top 5 or new, but I would check out, Tomcat and Jboss application server, along with the Struts and Seam frameworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One key aspect is developer productivity. There has been some excellent research and presentations done in this space by Matt Raible (generally, the non-EE space) and Adam Bien for the EE6 space.

Comment: Thanks.. I like the reference. I wanted some starting point and this serves as an Ideal one

Answer (score 1):

For all my quick and working web solutions I use [Grails](https://grails.org/).  It gives productivity, reasonable performance. It is supported by VMWare, so long term support looks OK.

Answer (score 1):

The ability of your application to successfully evolve over time has more to do with your software architecture than it has to do with either your technology or methodology. However, your choice of technologies and methodologies will influence how you architect your software.

First off, know what you are up against. In that late 1960s, people started studying what happens to applications over time. Over the last 40 years, those observations have been turned into a set of laws (c.f. Meir Lehman). This stuff might seem obvious, but it is a good starting place:

- As a system evolves, its complexity increases unless work is done to maintain or reduce it.
- The functionality of a system must be continually increased to maintain user satisfaction over its lifetime. The quality of a system will appear to decline unless it is rigorously maintained and adapted to operational environment changes.

If your in this for the long haul, the biggest questions are probably organizational and not technical. For example, what technologies does the development staff already know and enjoy using? If the developers plan to stick with the company for 5-10 years, ask what it is about the future that excites them. The best places to collect ideas about "hot" Web app technologies is http://www.infoq.com/.

Consider what methodologies are a good fit to both the technical and business culture of your organization. Agile development is great, but it isn't the right fit for every organization or every environment.

Consider vendors. I worked at a site once that was a true-blue IBM shop because IBM made solid software and hardware. However, the client was really locked into the vendor. The client was still using token ring networks and OS/2 in 1997. Give yourself some room to switch tools and technologies when the need arises. A living, breathing application almost never survives a decade of use without switching technology stacks at least once.

To really create a software design that will hold up to changes in the business environment, follow the old adage "build one to throw away". We once built a new system using a new operating system, a new programming paradigm, a switch from green-screen terminal to fat-client GUIs... it was a complete reinvention of the company's information technology. We would have never succeeded if we had not build a prototype and throw it away. We didn't pick all the right technologies and methods the the first time around, when we build the prototype. But we got the chance to correct those mistakes when we built the production system. This only works if you can create a prototype and then throw it away before it is used for real business needs. Once the application goes into production, the window to "throw one away" is gone.

Best of luck!
-Aaron